# Filter inner array only by matching the search string dynamic

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a nested array and i have a search feature in my application, i want to filter the data by the search string the user type, i have tried mostly every solution but none worked for me,i want to filter only the inner array but so far the solutions i have tried returned the whole array if even one match is found

```
   [{menu: "Users"
   order: 100
   sub_menus: [{
   order: 100
   sub_menu: "Create User"
   uuid: "3c502d2a-52b2-4cf0-b121-fed3b13693ef"
   },{
   order: 10
   sub_menu: "Modify"
   uuid: "3c502d2a-52b2-4cf0-b121-fed3b13695ef"
   }]
   uuid: "3c502d2a-52b2-4cf0-b121-fed3b13693ef"
}]
```

I have tried many solution from internet but not expected output,below function returns all the objects in array if one is true where as i want only objects inside sub_menus whose sub_menu name matches with the search value i provide

```
function filterMenu(menuList) {
    return menuList.filter((menu) =>
      menu.sub_menus.some((subMenu) =>
        subMenu.sub_menu.toLowerCase().match(searchMenu.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: please elaborate more what you want to achieve (e.g. add the expected output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two steps:

1. For each menu, calculate what the filtered sub menu would look like
2. Return the menus with the filtered sub menus, but ignore those with no results

This would look similar to this:

```js
function filterMenu(menuList) {
    const mapped = menuList.map((menu) => ({
        // Copy all fields from menu
        ...menu,
        // But overwrite sub_menus with a filtered version
        sub_menus: menu.sub_menus.filter((subMenu) =>
            subMenu.sub_menu.toLowerCase().match(searchMenu.toLowerCase())
        )
    }));
    // Now ignore menus that have no submenus
    return mapped.filter(menu => menu.sub_menus.length);
}
```

You can remove the last `.filter` in case you still want to receive menus with no sub menus.

Mind that using `.match` over `.includes` for strings might be unwanted (the input will be seen as a RegEx, which might even lead to a security issue due to RegEx DoS), but that's an unrelated issue.

Comment: Hi it worked great, can you tell me how to use .includes in this, as far as I thought it is used in arrays @Kelvin Schoofs

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array of all sub_menus and filter out for the one that matches the search.

```js
let menu = [{
  menu: "Users",
  order: 100,
  sub_menus: [{
    order: 100,
    sub_menu: "Create User",
    uuid: "3c502d2a-52b2-4cf0-b121-fed3b13693ef"
  }, {
    order: 10,
    sub_menu: "Modify",
    uuid: "3c502d2a-52b2-4cf0-b121-fed3b13695ef"
  }],
  uuid: "3c502d2a-52b2-4cf0-b121-fed3b13693ef"
}]

const getSub = str => menu.map(e => e.sub_menus).flat().filter(e => e.sub_menu === str);

console.log(getSub('Modify'));
```

Comment: Its changing the data structure like in example i have 2 objects sub_menus array,I want that if i search user the whole architecture of data stay same but in sub array it will be only create user,the modify one will be removed